# download csv file not support chinese characters

Tags: javascript, csv

I wanna make a download csv function in my website, it will download the table infomation into csv. However, it contains chinese characters when I m using Excel to open it, it cannot show the chinese characters correctly. Is there any method to make it support chinese characters? thanks

```
function downloadCSV() {
const table = document.getElementById('download_table');
var rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
var csv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
        row.push('"' + data + '"');
    }
    csv.push(row.join(','));
}
var csv_string = csv.join('\n');

// Download
var filename = 'export_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.display = 'none';
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
link.setAttribute('download', filename);
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

}

Comment: This seems javascript, not java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add BOM at the start of the csv string.

```
var csv_string = "\ufeff"+csv_string;
```